# AWS remove old files in repo S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awk

I have a repository in s3 with files with old dates (< 20-10).
I want to delete only those files.
The problem is that when you apply xargs rm you can't delete the files because it concatenates by default the date with the name d

```
aws s3 ls s3://my_repo/

2019-10-17 06:07:09       9307 20191017_060016_00112_u246w_0950f96f-a55a-4ce5-b0f3-b271ecb8fe90
2019-10-17 06:07:09     467791 20191017_060016_00112_u246w_94bbd3a2-76ea-4c04-8189-d963168ea34b
2019-10-21 19:35:12       1633 20191021_193156_01159_myrsw_2e68c0e4-b1a3-4abf-94b3-797ef653b742
2019-10-21 19:35:12       1643 20191021_193156_01159_myrsw_3491c665-82e3-475c-bba2-35e7d61d7912

aws s3 ls s3://my_repo/ | awk '$1 < "2019-10-20 00:00:00" '

2019-10-17 06:07:09       9307 20191017_060016_00112_u246w_0950f96f-a55a-4ce5-b0f3-b271ecb8fe90
2019-10-17 06:07:09     467791 20191017_060016_00112_u246w_94bbd3a2-76ea-4c04-8189-d963168ea34b

aws s3 ls s3://my_repo/ | awk '$1 < "2019-10-20 00:00:00" {print $0}' |  xargs -0 rm --

rm: cannot remove '2019-10-17 06:07:09       9307 20191017_060016_00112_u246w_0950f96f-a55a-4ce5-b0f3-b271ecb8fe90': File name too long
```

Comment: Print `$2` instead of `$0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `aws s3 ls`, you can use:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "Contents[?LastModified<='2019-06-01'].[Key]" --output text
```

This will list the name (Key) of objects created before the given date.